Why my serial monitor receive reverse byte from STM32F407 UART?
I am using Keil STMF407ZGT6's USART1 to send some data(encoded in UTF-8) which is "00000" to my pc(x86_64). My usart setting is 9600 baud rates, 8 bits data without parity, 1 stop bit. But I am receiving data reversed like this in hex.

I'm confused '0' is 0x30 in ASCII code, and 0Xe0 is just the 0x30 'reversed' in some way. I tried to change the code format to ANSI or GBK but doesn't work, I also changed serial monitor but every of them shows the same message received.
Why does this happening? And how to fix it?

This is my uart settings.



This is my code.



OK, but with what hardware you connect the STM32 to PC? State any chip between STM32 and PC and where in the PC you connect to, which port or adapter? Have you tried a delay between initializing the UART and sending data? Or sending data in the while loop every 100ms maybe? What macro is that which is supposed to take the length of the array?

How are you reading the serial output? What is the chip itself connected to? There are several configuration options for inverting data levels.

Tip: Search on LSB versus MSB,

Looks like bits and byte order are reverse. Try to send "12345" to confirm that.
